# Neo4j supports Windows but the recommended filesystem is ext4

Tags: neo4j, ntfs

The Neo4j manual shows that windows is supported, but the minimum filesystem is Ext4, what are the compromises for NTFS.

Comment: context: please do not advise to use linux(I would in production), I am asking this question for a Software architecture course https://github.com/delftswa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4J is written on java and uses JDK abstraction of file system. So developers **can** recommend you some operation system, but theoretically it will work on FAT or even on proprietary OS of your cooler (if it is run with Java control).

Just provide your own measurement of performance at possible target OS and select best one.